# Replacing shared_ptr elements in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

I have a vector of shared_ptrs as below.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SharedThing>> things;
```

Now let's say I push a number of shared_ptrs onto the vector and each element now has a reference count of 1.

When I need to replace one of those elements with a new shared_ptr I want the old shared_ptr to go out of scope. Will regular element assignment achieve this or will it just copy the shared_ptr contents. For example:

```
things.at(0) = new_shared_ptr;
```

Will this decrement the reference count of things.at(0) and increment the count of new_shared_ptr?

Comment: Yes use s debugger to prove this.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, basically you are right.
To be more accurate, the reference count of previous shared_ptr at(0) will be decremented. And then you assign it with a new shared_ptr, which may have the count 1. Looks like the reference count at(0) is the same, but it changed and changed back.

You can verify it by std::shared_ptr::use_cout()

For more details, we can debug into the STL, when
`things.at(0) = new_shared_ptr;`

> include/c++/4.8.3/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:556

```
  __shared_count&
  operator=(const __shared_count& __r) noexcept
  {    
_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>* __tmp = __r._M_pi;
if (__tmp != _M_pi)
  {    
    if (__tmp != 0)
      __tmp->_M_add_ref_copy();
    if (_M_pi != 0)
      _M_pi->_M_release();
    _M_pi = __tmp;
  }    
return *this;
  }
```

The new one _M_add_ref_copy(), then previous one _M_release(), which will decrease the _M_use_count by 1.

Answer (score 3):

> When I need to replace one of those elements with a new shared_ptr I
>   want the old shared_ptr to go out of scope. Will regular element
>   assignment achieve this?

The shared pointer in the vector won't go out of scope,
but it will replace the managed object with the new one given.

Calling:

```
things.at(0) = new_shared_ptr;
```

will preserve the count at 1.

Here is an easy way to observe this behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main(){

  //vector with a shared pointer
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> things;
  things.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(1));

  //prints 1
  std::cout << things.at(0).use_count() << '\n';

  //assign a new value
  things.at(0) = std::make_shared<int>(2);

  //still prints 1
  std::cout << things.at(0).use_count() << '\n';
}
```

Although not a part of your question, it is often advised to use `make_shared` instead of a `new`.

Comment: That's not "preserving the count", you're reading the count from an entirely different object.  (Use count is not part of the `shared_ptr`, but part of the metadata block for the target object)